# WP Как переопределить URL адресс в ссылке Log in to Reply?

Tags: wordpress, комментарии

В блоке комментариев WordPress страницы, если пользователь не зарегистрирован, то ему, чтобы оставить комментарий, предлагают зарегистрироваться

```
<?php
                comment_reply_link(array(
                    'reply_text' => __('Reply', 'am'),
                    'depth'      => $depth,
                    'max_depth'  => $args['max_depth'],
                    'login_text' => __('Log in to Reply', 'am'),
                    'before' => '',
                ));
?>
```

Вопрос - как вместо того, чтобы вести пользователя на страницу

```
<a rel="nofollow" class="comment-reply-login" href="https://test.local/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fausuppreview-dev.local%2Freview%2Ftest-company-1%2F">Log in to Reply</a>
```

в href поставить адрес кастомной страницы? К примеру `/register/`
Пробовал через хук-фильтр

```
function custom_comment_reply_link($link, $args, $comment, $post) {
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        $link = str_replace('wp-login.php', 'register', $link);
    }
    return $link;
}
add_filter('get_comment_reply_link', 'custom_comment_reply_link', 10, 4);
```

Не сработал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это надо сделать таким образом.

```php
/**
 * Filters the comment form default arguments.
 *
 * @param array $defaults The default comment form arguments.
 */
function my_comment_form_defaults( $defaults ) {
    if ( ! isset( $defaults['must_log_in'] ) ) {
        return $defaults;
    }

    $defaults['must_log_in'] = str_replace( 'wp-login.php', 'register', $defaults['must_log_in'] );

    return $defaults;
}

add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'my_comment_form_defaults' );
```

А в вашем варианте название фильтра неправильное. Не

```
add_filter('get_comment_reply_link', 'custom_comment_reply_link', 10, 4);
```

а

```
add_filter('comment_reply_link', 'custom_comment_reply_link', 10, 4);
```

Comment: Спасибо, но пока что это не помогло... адресс в href остаеться все тем же. Пробовал вызывать как в файле `functions.php` так и tempate форми.

Comment: Тема-то какая? Там выводится эта строка. С 2021 точно работает, я дебажил (и вообще всегда выкладываю рабочий код).

Comment: Тема кастомная, и форма комментирования тоже кастомная.

Comment: @BlackStar1991 дополнил ответ